# How do I conditionally declare variables in go templates?

Tags: go-templates, helmfile, sprig-template-functions

I am working on `helmfile` and stuck at the point where I want the conditional variable declaration. Roughly like this but in go standard templates.

```py
ENV = "prod"
folder = ""
if ENV == "prod":
    folder = "production"
elif ENV == "qa"
    folder == "qa"
else
    folder = "dev"
```

How can I achieve something like that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`{{if}}` action](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Actions) and the `eq` template function to compare the `ENV` variable to certain values:

```
{{$ENV := "prod"}}
{{$folder := ""}}

{{if eq $ENV "prod"}}
    {{$folder = "production"}}
{{else if eq $ENV "qa"}}
    {{$folder = "qa"}}
{{else}}
    {{$folder = "dev"}}
{{end}}
```

Note that this is not "conditional declaration". We declare `$folder` "unconditionally" and used `{{if}}` to change its value.

Here's a runnable demo to test the above template:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))

    for _, env := range []string{"prod", "qa", "other"} {
        if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, env); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

const src = `{{$ENV := .}}
{{- $folder := "" -}}

{{- if eq $ENV "prod"}}
    {{$folder = "production"}}
{{else if eq $ENV "qa"}}
    {{- $folder = "qa" -}}
{{else}}
    {{- $folder = "dev" -}}
{{end}}
$ENV = {{$ENV}}; $folder = {{$folder}}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/H935kwuGmhQ)):

```
$ENV = prod; $folder = production
$ENV = qa; $folder = qa
$ENV = other; $folder = dev
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do have the Sprig functions available to you (in both standard Helm and in Helmfile) then you can create a [`dict`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html), then look up a value in it (probably using the standard `index` function) with a `default`.

```
{{ $ENV := ... }}
{{ $folders := dict "prod" "production" "qa" "qa" }}
{{ $folder := index $folders $ENV | default "dev" }}
```

Helmfile also has [its own version of `get`](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile#templates) that includes defaulting functionality; so in Helmfile specifically (but not in core Go `text/template` or the Sprig extensions, so not standard Helm) you can say

```
{{/* get "key" "default" (dict ...) */}}
{{ $folder := get $ENV "dev" $folders }}
```

Both of these in Python would look like:

```py
folders = { "prod": "production", "qa": "qa" }
folder = folders.get(ENV, "dev")
```

which should be equivalent to your logic.